# Add prefix/suffix to all elements in space-separated string

Tags: bash, sh

Consider you have a shell variable `foo`, whose value is

```sh
echo ${foo}
# Output: elementA elementB elementC
```

Now I would like to add same prefix `__PREFIX__` and suffix `__SUFFIX__` to the elements, so that

```sh
echo ${new_foo}
# Output: __PREFIX__ElementA__SUFFIX__  __PREFIX__ElementB__SUFFIX__  __PREFIX__ElementC__SUFFIX__
```

What is the simplest way to achieve that?

---

<s>Because I'm not sure how such an operation should be called, the title is probably not describing the problem correctly.</s>

Thanks for the comments and answers. The title has been updated.

Comment: You don't have an array; you just have a string with spaces in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a *proper* array,

```
foo=(a b c)
```

you can add a prefix using the `/#` operator and add a suffix with the `/%` operator. It does have to be done in two steps, though.

```
$ foo=(a b c)
$ foo=("${foo[@]/#/__PREFIX__}")
$ foo=("${foo[@]/%/__SUFFIX__}")
$ declare -p foo
declare -a foo=([0]="__PREFIX__a__SUFFIX__" [1]="__PREFIX__b__SUFFIX__" [2]="__PREFIX__c__SUFFIX__")
```

If you just have a space-separated string, you can use `//`:

```
$ foo="a b c"
$ foo="__PREFIX__${foo// /__SUFFIX__ __PREFIX__}__SUFFIX__"
$ echo "$foo"
__PREFIX__a__SUFFIX__ __PREFIX__b__SUFFIX__ __PREFIX__c__SUFFIX__
```

Answer (score 1):

With `sed` you could do:

```
prefix=__PREFIX__
suffix=__SUFFIX__
new=$(sed -E "s/(\S)(\s|$)/\1$suffix  /g;s/(\s|^)(\S)/$prefix\2/g" <<< $foo)
```

which outputs:

```
__PREFIX__elementA__SUFFIX__ __PREFIX__elementB__SUFFIX__ __PREFIX__elementC__SUFFIX__
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy to read approach, but it's probably the worst from an efficiency standpoint.

```
foo="elementA elementB elementC"

PREFIX=__PREFIX__
SUFFIX=__SUFFIX__
for f in ${foo}
do
  new_foo="${new_foo} ${PREFIX}${f}${SUFFIX}"
done
echo ${new_foo}
```